# How to make AndroidScheduler.mainThread work with a Scala Observable?

Tags: android, scala, rx-scala

I have an Observable in my oncreate and I want to get the results on my main thread. But since The AndroidScheduler.mainThread works with just Java Observable, I am unable to compile it. Here's the code

```
val L=List(1,2,3)
val a=Observable.from(L).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(i=>println(i))
```

Here 'a' is a rx.scala.lang Observable. And this is the compile time error I am getting

```
 Error:(38, 70) type mismatch;
 found   : rx.Scheduler
 required: rx.lang.scala.Scheduler
 val a=Observable.from(L).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(i=>println(i))
                                                                 ^
```

Please help in solving this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`JavaConversions`](http://reactivex.io/rxscala/scaladoc/index.html#rx.lang.scala.JavaConversions$) class contains the method you need to convert from a "Java Scheduler" (the `rx.Scheduler`) to a "Scala Scheduler" (the `rx.lang.scala.Scheduler`) - `javaSchedulerToScalaScheduler`:

```
val a=Observable.from(L)
        .observeOn(JavaConversions.javaSchedulerToScalaScheduler(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()))
        .subscribe(i=>println(i))
```